# Exception while opening popup window in Android app

Tags: android, popupwindow, inflate-exception

I am getting the following exception, while trying to call this method.

> Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback 08-21
>   00:12:43.454  10843-10843/common.barter.com.barterapp
>   E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file
>   line #2: Error inflating class 
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)

```
public class GlobalHome extends ActionBarActivity{
----------------------
----------------------
private void showLocationPopup() {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
            this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_location,
            (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_location_popup));
    PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(
            layout,
            100,
            100,
            true);
    // The code below assumes that the root container has an id called 'main'
    pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

}
}
```

Layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dip"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/switch_thumb_material_light"
android:id="@+id/layout_location_popup"
>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:text="Test Pop-Up"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please post the layout file you're trying to inflate?

Comment: @anytoe updated the post.

Comment: I can see a tiny popup in the middle of the screen if I change the color without an error, e.g: android:background="#FFFFFF", so maybe your question should better be: Why does this color not work for a popup?

Comment: Thanks @anytoe, but I don't see the content(The textview).

Comment: See answer below and accept if it solves the problem for you, please

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
private void showLocationPopup() {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
            getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_location,(ViewGroup) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.layout_location_popup));
    PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(
            layout,
            100,
            100,
            true);
    // The code below assumes that the root container has an id called 'main'
    pw.setWindowLayoutMode(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

}
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dip"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:id="@+id/layout_location_popup">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:text="Test Pop-Up"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I've changed the colour, as the one you picked does not work. Seems not be a typical android colour to me. Further I've set the layout width and height to 'WRAP_CONTENT'. For me it shows up fine now in the middle of the screen with a white background.